# runtime error 48 while using function in dll in VBA?

Tags: vba, dll, coreldraw

I have to use a DLL file in VBA code.

After  declaring in code I am unable to use or call the function. The error is: `file not found` and error code is `runtime 48`.

The help I need is to know how the function in dll will be called and initialized.

```
Option Explicit

Public x As Integer

Private Declare Function XYZ Lib " H:\google drive\laser machine\software\Development\delete\squareDLL\x64\Debug\squareDLL.dll" (ByVal x As Double) As Double

Sub main()
    x = 20
    Call XYZ(x)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your code?

Comment: Specifying the DLL file (where it came from, what software package) might be really handy too, someone else may have experience with it. Of course, if it's something proprietary/written in-house, that may not be the case.

Comment: it is created from vb C++  since i am beginner in vba so please let me know basics of dll file to be used in vba and how to call

Comment: There will be a lot of articles on the net about using DLL's, without any information, the answer would be what the poster thinks and of no use to you.  Please supply DLL details name etc, function you're calling, the underlying code of that function etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Public x As Integer
Private Declare Function XYZ Lib " H:\google drive\laser machine\software\Development\delete\squareDLL\x64\Debug\squareDLL.dll" (ByVal x As Double) As Double

Sub main()
x = 20
Call XYZ(x)
End Sub
```

Comment: @greg-449 The OP posted this instead of editing their question. You should have flagged it as not an answer, not fix the formatting.